# Salesforce Mobile

Tags: mobilesdk, android, push-notification

I did some research about Mobile SDK and Marketing Cloud SDK, but I didn't understand how can I do the connection between Salesforce and Android, for example.

I'm trying to understand if I have to use Firebase to send the notification to my Android app or if Salesforce have this structure to do this job, but I can't find anything about it. Is it necessary to use Firebase to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Marketing Cloud SDK uses GCM, as of 20180328, to deliver messages to your application.  As such, you need to create a project with Google, obtain the LEGACY SERVER KEY and the Project ID (aka GCM Sender ID).  With those 2 pieces of data you can 1) create a new application in the Marketing Cloud and 2) initialize the SDK in your application with your newly created Application ID, Access Token and GCM Sender ID.

Your application will, upon initialization of the SDK, register the device with GCM and get a push token.  That token will be provided to the Marketing Cloud servers by the SDK.

Now you can send push messages to your application :)

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks for answer. So is it really necessary use Google to send push, even using Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Apple and Google provide the conduit for push messages.  There is no way to get a push message on to a device without them.

Comment: Ok Bill, thank you again.
I'm trying send the push using following the documentation, but unsuccessfully.
Have you any additional resource about it?

Comment: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html

Comment: The biggest thing people get wrong: we need the GCM, not Firebase, Server Key.  To get that you _must_ create your application in the Marketing Cloud with the LEGACY SERVER KEY.